# Trying to convert Date to the format in the body below, but wasn't successful

Tags: java, datetime, date-format

Need help in converting a date to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format without using `CONVERT()` function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which programming language are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Date date = new Date();
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String s = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(s);
```

Documentation about the `SimpleDataFormat`can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)